# Why is @ConstructorBinding not working even though @EnableConfigurationProperties or @ConfigurationPropertiesScan is used?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have problem with getting `@ConstructorBinding` working in my app. I also use Bean Definition DSL. Here's the app:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CallMeProperties::class)
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = ["pl.app"])
class CallmeApp

fun main(){
    runApplication<CallmeApp> {
        addInitializers(appBeans())
    }
}

fun appBeans() = org.springframework.context.support.beans {
    bean<CallMeProperties>()

    bean {
        TestRouter(ref()).testRouter()
    }
}

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "callme")
data class CallMeProperties(
       var property1: String,
       var property2: String
)
```

Here's `application.yml`:

```
callme:
  property1: "Test1"
  property2: "Test2cfg"
```

And `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.1.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.3.72"
}

group = "pl.app.callme"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "Hoxton.SR6"

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core")
    runtimeOnly("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

I also tried setting up only `@EnableConfigurationProperties(CallMeProperties::class)` and only '@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = ["pl.app"])' but this doesn't work neither.

I am getting exception saying `@EnableConfigurationProperties or @ConfigurationPropertiesScan must be used to add @ConstructorBinding type`

Full exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pl.app.callme.CallMeProperties#0': @EnableConfigurationProperties or @ConfigurationPropertiesScan must be used to add @ConstructorBinding type pl.app.callme.CallMeProperties
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:291) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at pl.app.callme.CallmeAppKt.main(CallmeApp.kt:36) ~[main/:na]
    at pl.app.callme.CallmeAppKt.main(CallmeApp.kt) ~[main/:na]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you seeing any error?

Comment: oh, of course I forgot to add it... Yes, I have got error: `@EnableConfigurationProperties or @ConfigurationPropertiesScan must be used to add @ConstructorBinding type`

I also edited question.

Answer (score 0):

So the real problem is misleading exception message.

Removing

```kotlin
bean<CallmeProperties>()
```

from beans definition resolves the problem.